# How to get value of a specific xml element?

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

[image: My XML]

I want to get Value of "pass" element and check if it is same with textbox
and if text in the textbox is same with the value of the "pass" element in xml file , I should open the next form.

Here is my C# code :

```
             sifre = txtsifre.Text;

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\Resources\\gbirligi.xml");

            var cek = from ss in doc.Root.Descendants("Siparis")
                         where ss.Element("pass").Value == sifre
                         select ss;
            if (cek.Count()==1)
            {
                AnaMenu mn = new AnaMenu();
                this.Hide();
                mn.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid password");
            }
```

I could not find what am I doing wrong. Xml file is being read properly but anytime it goes to else part.

Please help me what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get your result to a list. Thats why it can't get a count.

Also I suggest that to make your control with `cek.Count() > 0` not `cek.Count() == 1`. Try this:

```
var cek = (from ss in doc.Root.Descendants("Siparis")
                     where ss.Element("pass").Value == sifre
                     select ss).ToList();
        if (cek.Count() > 0)
        {
            AnaMenu mn = new AnaMenu();
            this.Hide();
            mn.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid password");
        }
```